# Getting Broadcom BCM43430 WiFi working

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

Im trying to get the integrated WiFi to work on a CSL-Mini-PC-stick. On windows the chipset was displayed as BCMSDH43xx. Error messages in dmesg (see below) seem to suggest it's a BCM43430 chipset. It doesn't show up in either lspci/lsusb or lshw.

(Re)loading the brcmfmac module leads to an error in dmesg:

```
brcmfmac_sdio mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin failed with error -2
brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

Somone suggested [this](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/T100TA#WiFi)) guide for gettin the wifi up and running so I downloaded and extracted the .deb for firmware-brcm80211 and put the brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin in /lib/firmware/brcm I looked for the nvram file in /efivars but couldn't find any.

After unloading and loading the module I got another error in dmesg:

```
brcmfmac_sdio mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt failed with error -2
```

so googling around for that file I found one on a raspberry pi [github repo](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/blob/master/brcm80211/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt) and put it in /lib/firmware/brcm. This lead to repeating erros in dmesg:

```
brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

Anybody's got any ideas?

Comment: Hi Kiehne, have you solved this problem? I encountered the exactly same problem with a Baytrail tablet, I tried same steps you mentioned here and got similar results. Any idea about how to fix this driver issue?

Comment: Sorry I have to disappoint you. I ended up giving up on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried extracting driver files from Android image coming with this tablet, it's still not working. Looks like those devices are not Linux friendly.

Comment: Two years later, I'm having the same problem with a Wintel W8 Pro containing (according to dmesg) a Broadcom 43455 Wifi chip.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by softlinking /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt to the txt-file that has pi3 in it's name in the same directory.